# Showing that there exists a solution to an equation and writing its Taylor polynomial.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, implicit-function-theorem

I need to show that for the equation $e^{y}+2y+x=1$, there exists a solution to $y=f(x)$ near $x=y=0$, and then I need to write $f(x)$ as its 3rd degree Taylor polynomial expanded at $x=0$. Is there any hint I could have to figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$e^y+2y+x=1 \tag 1$$
Obviously $(x=0,y=0)$ is solution. Expanding to series around this point :

$$y=a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4+a_5x^5+...$$

$$e^{a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4+a_5x^5+...}+2(a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4+a_5x^5+...)+x-1=0$$

Expanding to series leads to :
$$(3a_1+1)x+(3a_2+\frac12 a_1^2)x^2+(3a_3+a_1a_2+\frac16 a_1^3)x^3+...=0$$
Then we have to solve 
$$3a_1+1=0$$
$$3a_2+\frac12 a_1^2=0$$
$$3a_3+a_1a_2+\frac16 a_1^3=0$$
$$\text{etc.}$$
The result is :
$$a_1=-\frac13$$
$$a_2=-\frac{1}{54}$$
$$a_3=0$$
$$a_4=\frac{1}{8748}$$
$$\text{etc.}$$
$$y(x)=-\frac13 x -\frac{1}{54}x^2+\frac{1}{8748}x^4+\frac{1}{196830}x^5+...$$
NOTE for information :

This equation can be solved analytically, but it requires a special function.

Of course, this is not the kind of answer expected by the OP.
$$\frac12 e^y=-y+\frac{1-x}{2}$$
$$(-y+\frac{1-x}{2})e^{-y}=\frac12$$
$$(-y+\frac{1-x}{2})e^{-y+\frac{1-x}{2}}=\frac12e^{\frac{1-x}{2}} \tag 2$$
The solution of an equation of this kind :
$$Xe^X=Y$$
cannot be expressed with a finit number of elementary functions. It requires a special function, namely the Lambert W function :
$$X=W(Y)$$
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html

With $\quad X=(-y+\frac{1-x}{2})\quad$ and $\quad Y=\frac12e^{\frac{1-x}{2}}\quad$ Eq.$(2)$ becomes $Xe^X=Y$ which solution is :
$$(-y+\frac{1-x}{2})=W\left(\frac12e^{\frac{1-x}{2}} \right)$$
The solution of Eq.$(1)$ is :
$$y=\frac{1-x}{2} - W\left(\frac12e^{\frac{1-x}{2}}\right)$$ 
Expanding the Lambert W function to series would lead to the same result as above.

Comment: Wow, you really took the time in helping me understand and I am truly grateful. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, this is the implicit function theorem. For the second part, I suggest the following. Differentiate your equation to get
$y'(x)e^{y(x)}+2y'(x)+1=0.$ Then, at $x=0$, knowing that $y(0) = 0$), we get $y'(0)+2y'(0) +1=0.$ Hence, $y'(0) = -\frac{1}{3}.$ For $y''(0)$ and $y'''(0)$, same idea.